# Apache mod_wsgi Flask 404 errors with large json files

Tags: python, json, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I have a flask app set up using mod_wsgi on apache. On one of the pages, I have a set of charts, each of which is pulling data (~2Mb per file) from a static route `@app.route('/data/<experiment_id>/<sensors>.json` where I use the json mimetype: `return Response(fn(**kwargs), mimetype="application/json")`. When I run this using the dev server on localhost it works fine, but on the deployment server I get sporadic 404 errors. Typically it will load 7 or 8 of the 10 files. If I navigate directly to the file location (e.g. http://my_server/data/test/noise.json) the (single) file always loads correctly.

My apache mod_wsgi config is as follows:

```
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
WSGIRestrictStdout Off
WSGIScriptReloading On

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias my_server

    ErrorLog logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/access_log common

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    WSGIDaemonProcess data_viewer user=my_user group=my_group processes=3 threads=10 home=/var/www/html/data_viewer
    WSGIScriptAlias /data_viewer /var/www/wsgi-scripts/data_viewer.wsgi

    <Location /data_viewer>
        WSGIProcessGroup data_viewer
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    </Location>

    <Directory /var/www/wsgi-scripts>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Is this likely to be a timeout issue, a process/threading issue, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but upping the number of threads to 15 seems to have solved the problem for now.